# Javascript Month, Week, Day View Calendars

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm yet to find a Javascript Library that offers a plugin which can output Events in a Calendar which supports:

- Month View
- Week View
- Day View

There is only [one](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/) so far which supports all views but thought it would be good to see if anyone else knows of any other Javascript Libraries (Plugins) which can support this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pay for one: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/outlook2007/defaultcs.aspx

I can't vouch for it, and you'd need to be using the .NET stack, but it does support Day, Week, and Monthly views.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ext Scheduler, super interactive scheduling component with support for any type of time resolution.

http://www.ext-scheduler.com/